# Update Post Meta for WooCommerce Stock Quantity Using Get Post Meta

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I need to modify the stock levels for inventory per product using a custom field.

These are the code snippets i have tried and modified.

The goal is to manually modify the inventory levels even when they're in stock so orders cannot be placed when stock is low and the add to cart button is removed.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'custom_product_inventory_settings'  );
function custom_product_inventory_settings( $post_id ) {

//  if ( isset( $_POST['_custom'] ) ) :

    $product = wc_get_product( $post_id );

    $stock_threshold = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_custom', true );

    if ( ! empty( $stock_threshold ) ) {

    $new_stock_quantity = $product->get_stock_quantity() - $stock_threshold;

    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_stock', $new_stock_quantity );

     wc_delete_product_transients( $post_id );

    }

//  endif;

}

// Save custom field
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_process_product_object', 'action_woocommerce_admin_process_product_object', 10, 1 );
function action_woocommerce_admin_process_product_object( $product ) {

 //   if ( isset( $_POST['_out_of_stock_threshold'] ) ) {

    $product->update_meta_data( 'custom_field', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['custom_field'] ) );

    $stock_threshold = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), 'custom_field', true );

    if ( ! empty( $stock_threshold ) ) {

    $new_stock_quantity = $product->get_stock_quantity() - $stock_threshold;

    // update_post_meta( $post_id, '_stock', $new_stock_quantity );

    $product->update_meta_data( 'custom_field', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['custom_field'] ) );

    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_stock', $new_stock_quantity );

    $post_id = $product->get_id();

     wc_delete_product_transients( $post_id );

    }
}
```

Maybe i need to use a different hook like `woocommerce_get_availability` or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your problem is, or what is happening when you run the code, but at first glance you are using a variable before declaring it:

```
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_stock', $new_stock_quantity );

$post_id = $product->get_id();
```

Also, is the custom field you are using really supposed to be called `custom_field`?

Comment: Thanks but what hook are you using?

Comment: I'm not using any hook, I'm just saying that your code tries to use a variable before it is instantiated.

Comment: Which variable? You must be using a hook to run the code?

Comment: Look at your own code